# Grails sorting ignoring case sensitive

Tags: grails, grails-orm

```
games = Game.where {
    categories.categoryName == currentCategory
    platform.platformName == chosenPlatform
    status == "okay"
}.list(sort: 'gameTitle', order: "asc", max: max, offset: offset)
```

So here I am sorting a game by its name, the problem is Uppercase letter comes first so Delta comes before bravo which should be the other way around. How do yo do this in grails?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Derived Properties

```
class Game {
    String title

   static mapping = {
       titleUpper formula: 'UPPER(title)'
   }
}
```

And your Listing

```
games = Game.where {
    categories.categoryName == currentCategory
    platform.platformName == chosenPlatform
    status == "okay"
}.list(sort: 'titleUpper', order: "asc", max: max, offset: offset)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is purely database - Grails/Gorm/Hibernate generates a query, sends it to your database and processes results - that's it. If your database sort's case sensitive then you have two options:

- set the column(or the whole database if possible) to be case insensitive.
- use a function (like `UPPER`, `LOWER`) in the `ORDER BY` clause (e.g. `ORDER BY UPPER(game_title)`

See http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#5.5.2.11%20Derived%20Properties for more on formula fields.

Comment: Hi, I cant see ORDER BY in grails documentation, how do you implement that? do i do ,list(sort: ORDER BY UPPER(game_title), order: "asc", max: max, offset: offset)?